# Using TTK Combobox, how do I use the returned value elsewhere in the program?

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

```
`enter code here`
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *

def on_field_change(index, value, op):
    choice=StringVar  
    print( "combobox updated to ", c.get() ) # does print the updated values
    #choice=c.get
    #return(choice)  # added a return for testing - not useful
chosen=StringVar 
chosen=""   
root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x200+10+10")
v = StringVar()
x = StringVar
chosen=StringVar 
chosen=""   
c = Combobox(root, textvar=v, values=["foo", "bar", "baz"])
c.set('foog')
c.grid(row=0, column=1)

#choice_label = ttk.Label(text='choice='+c.get() ) #does not update
choice_label = Label(text= c.get ) #does not update
choice_label = Label(text= v ) #does not update
choice_label.grid(row=3, column=0)

quit_button = ttk.Button(root, text="QUIT")
quit_button.grid(row=4, column=0)
quit_button['command'] = root.destroy
v.trace('w',on_field_change)
print('the new v is : ', c.get())  # does not print updated values
#x=v.trace('w',on_field_change)
#print('the new choice is : ', x ) # does not print updated values
# try to use the selected item in another label and for a dictionary search
mainloop()
```

`enter code here`

Multiple examples of binding an event handler to the combo box. Almost all just print the selected value from the event handler.
Other approaches trace a string variable to the event handler.

I can’t figure how to get the returned value into the main body. My goal would be to use it to become the text of a label and also be an index or key in a dictionary.

Advice appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, dont understand what you mean? Could include some example or what youve tried? Why doesnt `combobox.get()` work?

Comment: There's nothing unique to tkinter with this. Just store the value in a global variable or object attribute.

Comment: combobox.get() works fine in the event handler and I can print the new selection. So far, no luck in assigning it to any variable. Can I copy paste code somewhere? it's 18 lines.

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add a [mcve].

Comment: There is no point in the body of your program where it is even meaningful to try to retrieve the combobox selection - prior to `mainloop()`, no selection can possibly have been made yet, and after `mainloop()`, there is no combobox (or any other widget) still existing.  An event handler of some sort is precisely where you should be retrieving and using the value.

Comment: Thanks for comments. Perhaps Jason Harper is suggesting the structure is not optimal. The event handler ‘works’ in the example but

Comment: But so far, I don’t see how to use it elsewhere. The concept is that the chosen value ( a physical property, mass distance etc,

Comment: But so far, I don’t see how to use it elsewhere. The concept is that the chosen value ( a physical property, mass distance etc,) is first picked then used to load the dictionary into other combo boxes ( meters, feet, iynches) to do a unit conversion. 
Actually spent hours searching here and github for examples and written tens of scripts that don’t work. 
Further complicated as I would like the app to stay ‘live’ for the user to do other unit conversions.